# How To Define 2 FK in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> I have 2 lists of `item`  in `user` i need 2 fk in item table i tried
>   but it didnt work, what is wrong with the code

```
   public class User
        {
            [Key]
            public int id { get; set; }

        public List<item> a  { get; set; }
        public List<item> b { get; set; }


        public User()
        {
            a= new List<item>();
            b = new List<item>();
        }

    }

    public class item
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("a")]
        public long aFK { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("b")]
        public long bFK { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("a")]
        public virtual User a { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("b")]
        public virtual User b { get; set; }
    }



    public class usersDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<item> items { get; set; }
    }
    public static usersDB dataBase()
    {
        return new usersDB();
    }

   private static void Main(string[] args)
        {        
            using (var db = dataBase())
            {

                db.users.Add(new User() {id = 1});
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: so, do you have any errors?

Comment: Someone? Yes, YOU. You are the one who should make this an answerable question. You're never *entitled* to receive an answer. We do this for fun, nothing else. So make it a pleasure to answer your question. A problem description like "it didnt work" is always insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. instead `long` (in `aFK` &  `bFK`), you should use `int` - Type same as the foreign key.
2. you can't declare two non-nullable foreign-keys, becuse the default behavior is `CascadeOnDelete`, what is impossible in such a case. so you have to set them (`aFK` &  `bFK`) as nullable  (`int?`), or set `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` via Flunet-Api.

incidentally, if you want set the `ID` yoyrself (`id = 1`), you need avoid the default configuration: `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, by attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]`

so, this code  work:

```
class Program
{
    public static usersDB dataBase()
    {
        return new usersDB();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<usersDB>());

        using (var db = dataBase())
        {
            var user = new User() { id = 1};

            user.a.Add(new item());
            user.a.Add(new item());
            user.a.Add(new item());

            user.b.Add(new item());
            user.b.Add(new item());

            db.users.Add(user);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var db = dataBase())
        {
            var user = db.users.Find(1);
            Console.WriteLine(user.a.Count); //OUT: 3
            Console.WriteLine(user.b.Count); //OUT: 2
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<item> a { get; set; }
    public virtual List<item> b { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        a = new List<item>();
        b = new List<item>();
    }
}

public class item
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("a")]
    public int? aFK { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("b")]
    public int? bFK { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("a")]
    public virtual User a { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("b")]
    public virtual User b { get; set; }
}

public class usersDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<item> items { get; set; }
}
```